# How to prevent a Ubuntu server from being updated?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, permissions

I am creating a test system that will be run by others. It will have some kernel mods, and some of the default software in /usr/bin will be replaced. Because of this, I want to prevent the users from doing "sudo apt-get update" or "sudo apt-get install". These systems will not have any valuable data, and will mostly be behind corporate firewalls, and thus it is safe to completely punt on security-based releases.

FWIW, moving apt-* and dpkg* to /usr/dontusethese does not work because some other processes like (gag) MOTD updating relies on them being in /usr/bin and whine if they are not there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just configure `/etc/sudoers` appropriately so that only authorized users can run `apt-get`.

Comment: Doh, or that would work just as well as my response.

Comment: Prohibiting users from doing an action is a better solution than masking the update action by removing the repositories.

Comment: To close the loop, since people like recipes, here is what works well: "adminuser ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL, !/usr/bin/apt*, !/usr/bin/dpkg*"